# Replace image on hover with jquery: targeting issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image, jquery-hover

I've been struggling a bit with this as I'm fairly new with jquery, and I know the solution is staring me in the face.

I have a plugin in wordpress that renders jquery for me and it's working, so no issue there. There is a wordpress page that has image thumbnails, and on hover, the image is to be replaced with the same color version of the image.

I have got it somewhat right if you see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marioi/p8n5gbsh/) (I've copied an excerpt of the html from wordpress), BUT it uses the first image of the :nth-child() for all the images on that page. It's either a targeting issue (the images don't have their own ID's by the way) or I'm not reassigning new values to the variable (link, img, etc.) on hover. It keeps using the first image details, as you'll see in my jsfiddle.

Thank you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var link = $('.avia_image'),
    img = link.children('img:nth-child(1)'),
    orig = img.attr('src'),
    over = orig.replace('_1', '_2'); // this replaces the _1 in the filename with _2 for the 'over' variable assignment

link.hover(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', over);
}, function () {
    $(this).attr('src', orig);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle. Please Have a look at it.

http://jsfiddle.net/p8n5gbsh/5/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var link = $('a.avia_image');
    link.hover(function () {
        var img = $(this).children('img'),
        orig = img.attr('src'),
        over = orig.replace('_1', '_2');
        $(img).attr('src', over);
    }, function () {
        var img = $(this).children('img'),
        over = img.attr('src'),
        orig = over.replace('_2', '_1');
        $(img).attr('src', orig);
    });
});
```

Comment: too much repetition and going back and forth (.replace('_1','_2') and then replace back (_2, _1)...) instead of storing the original value and reusing it on hover out.

Comment: This code is for beginner developer who are are really new to JQuery/JavaScript. So made it simple to read it... :) Not considering the load on javascript engine or memory leak.

Comment: Vijay and Zoran, than you very much! It's working, and looking at how you changed the code makes sense to me now. I learn't something.

Comment: My pleasure Mario...!

Comment: Just one more question, if I wanted to target a specific wordpress page only so it doesn't apply to all avia_images on the site, how would I format `var link = $('a.avia_image');`. There is a parent class called "page-id-113" for example.

Comment: If there is a parent with class `page-id-113` and if you want such animation to happen with all images under it; then yes the code has to be like `var link = $('.page-id-113 a.avia_image');`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, I just wasn't sure of the format (ie. should I be using .children under page-id-113 for eg., or does everything shift up a level, if you know what I mean).

Comment: `$.children()` traverse single level down of parent

Answer (score 0):

This works, tested and I think it is optimal code (no same code twice).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
    var orig = "";   
    var img;
    var link = $('a.avia_image');
    link.hover(function () {        
        img = $(this).find("img");
        //img = link.children('img:nth-child(1)'),
        orig = img.attr('src');
        var over = orig.replace('_1', '_2'); // this replaces the _1 in the filename with _2 for the 'over' variable assignment        
        img.attr('src', over);
        console.log(over);
    }, function () {
        img.attr('src', orig);
        console.log(orig);
        //link.unbind;
    });
});
```

Comment: Zoran, thank for the optimization, I appreciate it. I had to give Vijay the correct answer tick. If I could give it to both of you, I would.

Comment: Doesn't mean you can't upvote mine if you are satisfied with it ;)